# Prove that $\mathbf{E}(X_{\tau_2}|\mathcal{F}_{\tau_1})=X_{\tau_1}$

Tags: martingales, stopping-times, filtrations

> Let $(X_n)$ be a martingale with respect to $(\mathcal{F}_n)$ and suppose $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ are bounded stopping times such that $\tau_1\leq \tau_2<B<\infty.$ Then $$\mathbf{E}(X_{\tau_2}|\mathcal{F}_{\tau_1})=X_{\tau_1}.$$

My attempt: One may assume that $X_n$ is nonnegative. The general case will follow directly. From [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3015862/show-that-ex-mathcalf-tau-sum-limits-n-in-mathbbnex-mathcalf-n), \begin{align*}\mathbf{E}(X_{\tau_2}|\mathcal{F}_{\tau_1})&=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathbf{E}(X_{\tau_2}|\mathcal{F}_n)\mathbf{1}_{\{\tau_1=n\}}=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\sum_{m=n}^\infty\mathbf{E}(X_m|\mathcal{F}_n)\mathbf{1}_{\{\tau_1=n,\tau_2=m\}}\\&=\sum_{m\in\mathbb{N}}\sum_{n=1}^m\mathbf{E}(X_m|\mathcal{F}_n)\mathbf{1}_{\{\tau_1=n,\tau_2=m\}} \end{align*}

How should I proceed further here to obtain $X_{\tau_1}$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, you could take advantage of the fact that $(X_n)_n$ is a martingale, right? Since $n \leq m$ it holds that $\mathbb{E}(X_m \mid \mathcal{F}_n) = X_n$

Comment: @saz Thanks for your comment! I finally solved this problem!

Comment: @saz sorry for bringing up an old question, but I have some doubt about the second equality in the calculation above.  On the set $\{\tau_1 = n \}$ we have that $X_{\tau_2 } = \sum_{m=n }^{\infty}X_m1_{\{\tau_2 =m\}}$ and $1_{\{\tau_1 = n\}} E[X_{\tau_2 }|\mathcal F_n] = \sum_{m=n}^\infty 1_{\{\tau_1 = n\}}E[X_m1_{\{\tau_2 =m\}}|\mathcal F_n]$ but are we really allowed to "pull out" $1_{\{\tau_2 = m \}} $ from each conditional expectation for $m > n $?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by saz, using the fact that $\left(X_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is a martingale, we derive that for all $m\geqslant n\geqslant 1$, $\mathbb E\left[X_m\mid\mathcal F_n\right]=X_n$ hence continuing the computation, we get 
$$
\mathbf{E}(X_{\tau_2}|\mathcal{F}_{\tau_1}) =\sum_{m\in\mathbb{N}}\sum_{n=1}^mX_n\mathbf{1}_{\{\tau_1=n,\tau_2=m\}} =\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}X_n\sum_{m=n}^{+\infty}\mathbf{1}_{\{\tau_1=n,\tau_2=m\}} .
$$
Since 
$$
\sum_{m=n}^{+\infty}\mathbf{1}_{\{\tau_1=n,\tau_2=m\}}=\mathbf{1}_{\{n=\tau_1\leqslant \tau_2\}}
$$
and since $\tau_1\leqslant \tau_2$ almost surely, the last  indicator is simply $\mathbf{1}_{\{n=\tau_1\}}$ and we use an other time the result of the linked thread to get the result.

Comment: May I ask how you motivate the change of order of summation in the second equality here?