# Conditional expectation of martingale and two bounded stopping times

Tags: conditional-expectation, martingales, stopping-times

I am trying to prove the following:

Let $(X_n)$ be a martingale with respect to $(\mathcal{F}_n)$ and suppose $\tau_1$
and $\tau_2$ are bounded stopping times such that $\tau_1\le \tau_2 < B$, where $B < \infty$ is the bound. Then $E(X_{\tau_2}|\mathcal{F}_{\tau_1}) = X_{\tau_1}.$

What I've learned so far are definition and some properties of conditional expectation and martingales and I think no advanced knowledge is necessary to solve this.

But I could not combine that definition and  properties to produce good solution to this.

If anyone has any tips on how to do, I'd appreciate it a lot.

Comment: This is a (special case of a ) basic theorem called the Optional Sampling Theorem.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy But I found this problem located before the Optional Sampling Theorem (and martingale transform ...)

Comment: Take a look at this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3017226/36150